# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 events

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, event-handlers

I have an installation of sharepoint foundation. I was wondering if I can catch the event where a folder is created in a document library to do some more actions in sharepoint foundation. Can I follow the same tutorials and documentations as sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the event handlers are supported within Foundation and can be used in the same manner.